# Problem with manipulating data in array, react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, use-effect, use-state

I use `number` useParams to get a number from a URL path and `deck` array to get data from `data` array which contains 32 objects with id and src (URL for image) properties.

```js
// Images.js

const data = [
    {
        id:1,
        src:'https://###.com/###',
    },
    //...

const Images = () => {
    const {number} = useParams()
    const [deck, setDeck] = useState(data);
    //...
```

Then I use `useEffect` to fetch number from URL path and `setCards()` function to display proper amount of cards based on a given number from the URL by deleting indexes from `number` to `deck.length`. `shuffle()` function does not matter here it just places objects in a random order.

```js
// Images.js

useEffect(() => {
  fetch(`http://localhost:3000/play/${number}`).then(setCards(number));
}, [number]);

const setCards = (number) => {
  let tempDeck = deck;
  tempDeck.splice(number, deck.length);
  shuffle(tempDeck);
  setDeck(tempDeck);
};
```

I also use this piece of code to render the proper amount of cards from the web page by routing to the proper URL path:

```
// Home.js

<div className="btn-group">
  <Link to="/play/8">
    <button className="btn">8 cards</button>
  </Link>
  <Link to="/play/16">
    <button className="btn">16 cards</button>
  </Link>
  <Link to="/play/24">
    <button className="btn">24 cards</button>
  </Link>
  <Link to="/play/32">
    <button className="btn">32 cards</button>
  </Link>
</div>;
```

Whenever I make an initial render and for example select "24 cards" button everything is fine, 24 out of 32 cards are displayed as should be, but when I come back to the "main page" and select a higher value of cards in this case it would be 32 from "32 cards" button, browser will display only 24 cards instead of 32. How can I fix it?

Comment: try with let tempDeck = [...deck] in setCards function;

Comment: @FrancescoClementi funziona, grazie!

Comment: daje! scrivo una risposta più argomentata per gli altri così puoi accettarla

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With this code:

```
let tempDeck = deck;
tempDeck.splice(number, deck.length);
```

you are editing your original array.

You should consider to create a shallow copy of your original array and edit it:

```
let tempDeck = [...deck];
tempDeck.splice(number, deck.length);
```